# Nested Slider Controls using Webflow

Tags: nested, slider, webflow

I'm looking to put a slider control inside a slider control using WebFlow & Finsweet's CMS Slider Component.  As an example using the following data...

| Category | Topic |
| --- | --- |
| Cat 1 | Topic 1 |
| Cat 1 | Topic 2 |
| Cat 1 | Topic 3 |
| Cat 2 | Topic 4 |
| Cat 2 | Topic 5 |
| Cat 3 | Topic 6 |
| Cat 3 | Topic 7 |
| Cat 3 | Topic 8 |

What I want to achieve is a parent slider that shows the Category and a child slider that auto slides through the topics for the current category.  The child slider would not have any nav controls; all nav controls would be at the parent slider.   When the parent slider transitions to Cat 2, the child slider would then auto-cycle through the topics for Cat 2, including returning to Topic 4 after Topic 5.  Nav would move to Cat 3 and show those topics and another nav would restart back with Cat 1.

My first attempt at this has resulted in topics being disassociated with categories -- i.e. I can see Cat 1 with Topic 5.

Thanks in advance for any help.